# Firestore - How Can I Use UpdateDoc in Loop?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to decrement some values of product's count when user orders, I use updateDoc() in loop but it throws

> Error: Expected type 'af', but it was: a custom fg object

[image]

```js
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

let docs = [doc(db, "myCollection", 'a'), doc(db, "myCollection", 'b')];

async function test() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    let doc = await getDoc(docs[i]);
    console.log(doc.data());
    await updateDoc(doc, {
      num: increment(-1)
    })
  }
}

test();
```

[image]
How can I do that ?

Comment: Please edit the question and add code as text. [Don't add code images](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) as it's harder for us edit the code.

Answer (score 3):

The [`updateDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#updatedoc) function takes a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) as the first parameter and not a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot). Also you don't have to fetch the document before updating in this case. Try:

```
let docs = [doc(db, "myCollection", 'a'), doc(db, "myCollection", 'b')];

async function test() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    // doc in original code is a DocumentSnapshot
    // docs[i] is a DocumentReference
    await updateDoc(docs[i], {
      num: increment(-1)
    })
  }
}
```

You can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to run all the promises simultaneously as shown below:

```
let docs = ["a", "b"];

async function test() {
  const promises = docs.map((d) => {
    return updateDoc(doc(db, "myCollection", "b"), {
      num: increment(-1)
    })
  })
  await Promise.all(promises)
}
```

If you want to ensure that all updates are successful or none, then also checkout [Batched Writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).